# How to calculate color composite in Swift?

Tags: swift, image-processing, colors, core-graphics

I'm trying to create eraser tool for my photo editor app like in **Photoshop** (or that can remove defined color from the image), for example user will draw lines with desired color on image and my function will process the image after touch ends immediatly.

I created a method and it working well with some colors like white, black, yellow etc. but when I choose color with 0.5 alpha it's not working as desired!
I think my composite calculation is wrong so some one can help me with this please?

And here is my method for calculation :

```
extension UIImage {

func getImageRemovedDefinedColor(choosedColor: UIColor) -> UIImage? {

    let image = UIImage(data: self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!)!
    let rawImageRef: CGImage = image.cgImage!

    let components = choosedColor.cgColor.components!

    var colorMasking: [CGFloat] = []
    var red: CGFloat = 0.0, green: CGFloat = 0.0, blue: CGFloat = 0.0, alpha: CGFloat = 0.0

    if choosedColor.isEqual(UIColor.white) {

        colorMasking = [222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255]

    } else if choosedColor.isEqual(UIColor.black) {

        colorMasking = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

    } else {

        if components.count > 3 {

            red = components[0]
            green = components[1]
            blue = components[2]
            alpha = components[3]

            red = red * 255.0
            green = green * 255.0
            blue = blue * 255.0
            alpha = alpha * 255.0

            let redRange: [CGFloat] = {
                return [max(red - (alpha / 2.0), 0.0), min(red + (alpha / 2.0), 255.0)]
            }()

            let greenRange: [CGFloat] = {
                return [max(green - (alpha / 2.0), 0.0), min(green + (alpha / 2.0), 255.0)]
            }()

            let blueRange: [CGFloat] = {
                return [max(blue - (alpha / 2.0), 0.0), min(blue + (alpha / 2.0), 255.0)]
            }()

            colorMasking = [redRange[0], redRange[1], greenRange[0], greenRange[1], blueRange[0], blueRange[1]]
        }
    }

    print(colorMasking)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    let maskedImageRef = rawImageRef.copy(maskingColorComponents: colorMasking)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.translateBy(x: 0.0,y: image.size.height)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.draw(maskedImageRef!, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result

}
```

**Note:** Maybe my way completely wrong for doing this tool, if you have another idea about "how can we can create eraser tool with Swift" please share it.

All ideas acceptable, thanks in advance.